# Foreign key with distinguisher

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have one table STATUSES containing statuses for more tables:

```
TABLE_NAME | STATUS_ID | STATUS_NAME
===========+===========+============
TAB_1      |         1 | New
TAB_1      |         2 | Started
TAB_1      |         3 | Complete
TAB_2      |         1 | Empty
TAB_2      |         2 | Full
```

Table STATUSES has two column primary key (table_name,status_id).

Then I have the table TAB_1:

```
ID | STATUS_ID | TAB_VALUE
===+===========+==========
 1 |         1 | Value1
```

When I want to retrieve table values with status I use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT id,tab_value,status_name
FROM tab_1 t
JOIN statuses s ON (s.status_id=t.status_id AND s.table_name='TAB_1')
```

Now I'd like to create a foreign key from TAB_1 to STATUSES but STATUS_ID should be distinguished with table name!

I tried sth like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tab_1
ADD CONSTRAINT tab_1_status_fk FOREIGN KEY ('TAB_1',status_id)
REFERENCES statuses (table_name,status_id)
ENABLE;
```

Of course, this does not work (otherwise I wouldn't be here).

Is it possible to create such a foreign key with 'distinguisher'?

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd add the table name as a virtual column with a constant value, e.g.

```
alter table tab_1 add (table_name as ('TAB_1'));
```

And then create the fk using that

```
ALTER TABLE tab_1
ADD CONSTRAINT tab_1_status_fk FOREIGN KEY (table_name,status_id)
REFERENCES statuses (table_name,status_id)
ENABLE;
```

Edit: If you're on 12c or up, you can make the virtual column hidden; I think it'll still work with a FK...

```
alter table tab_1 add (table_name invisible as ('TAB_1'));
```

Comment: Hm, I don't like this solution. These additional columns are not virtual ones but real ones containing real (the same) data and occupying space (visible or invisible). These tables are huge, Then better solution would be to split merged statuses table into sparate status table for each table and create simple FK relation to them.

Comment: If you use the `as (EXPRESSION)` clause when creating a column, it'll be created as a virtual column, even if you don't use the `virtual` keyword. Try it out on a test table - the virtual flag will be set in the table DDL, and it won't allocate any more row storage on disk. But you might be right, rearchitecting might be a better choice. It's an awkward problem.